# Why when I upload file in codeigniter, it is saying temporary folder missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

why when I upload file in codeigniter, the output it says the temporary folder is missing?

I have already chmod the folder to 777. The source code as shown below. Thank you for the help.

The following is the jquery code the script.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#saveDokumenPelanForm').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if($('#dokumenPelan').val() == '')
                {
                    alert("Please Select the File");
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: BlankonApp.handleBaseURL() + '/InputPembangunan/ajax_upload', 
                        
                        method:"POST",
                        data:new FormData(this),
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData:false,
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

This is the modal for the form.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="addDokumenPelan" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form id="saveDokumenPelanForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Simpan Fail Pelan Kunci dan Lokasi Tapak</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">                       
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Muat Naik Fail</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="dokumenPelan" id="dokumenPelan" class="form-control" required>
            <input type="hidden" id="dokumenPelanInputId"  name="dokumenPelanInputId" class="form-control " value="{$input_id}">
            <input type="hidden" id="dokumenPelanId"  name="dokumenPelanId" class="form-control " value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveDokumenPelan">Muat Naik Fail</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This ajax upload code to upload the file.

```
function ajax_upload()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["dokumenPelan"]["name"]))
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('dokumenPelan'))
        {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            echo 'Name : '.$data["file_name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a "temp" or "tmp" folder in your root directory?

Comment: No, I do not have it. Just add in after your comment @Mikeyhun but still getting the same error message. The system works fine in laragon, but using IIS Microsoft web server it is giving the error message temporary folder is missing.

Comment: @Mikeyhun , solve the problem. I gave full access to directory C:\Windows\temp to users and iis_usrs . after that can upload the image.